# unable to delete anything

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I am using ssamsung galaxy core 2 . Since a last few days, i am getting this problem that i am unable to delete anything from my ggallery rather it be a video or an image . Whatever i delete it automatically comes back . I think this is somekind of virus . But my antivirus is unable to detect it . I used AVG,CM security and all other sorts of antivirus but none did help .please help. Reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have to be a virus. You should check if your media files are being synced.

Sync mostly goes both ways: If you delete files on your Galaxy, Google Drive, Dropbox or whatever you are using you must ensure that the files are not synced back to that device.

You can manually check all your storage devices if you don't know any other way around it. But sometimes you can do it through correct ***settings***. Some sync settings are not very user-friendly and others are ok.

In the event that it is a virus or malware after all: I would get rid of AVG a.s.a.p. since that program is known to be malware in 5 out of 10 times. Get another AV. I cannot tell you which one - maybe later ;-)

Comment: I would try out AVast!

http://www.tomsguide.com/us/best-antivirus,review-2588-7.html